# tensorflow hidden state doesn't seem to change

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to follow along with this [RNN tutorial on medium](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767), refactoring it as I go along. When I run my code, it appears to work, but when I tried to print out the `current state` variable to see what's happening inside the neural network, I got all `1`s. Is that expected behavior? Is the state not being updated for some reason? From what I understand, the `current state` should contain the latest values in the hidden layer for all batches, so it definitely shouldn't be all `1`s. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
def __train_minibatch__(self, batch_num, sess, current_state):
    """
    Trains one minibatch.

    :type batch_num: int
    :param batch_num: the current batch number.

    :type sess: tensorflow Session
    :param sess: the session during which training occurs.

    :type current_state: numpy matrix (array of arrays)
    :param current_state: the current hidden state

    :type return: (float, numpy matrix)
    :param return: (the calculated loss for this minibatch, the updated hidden state)
    """
    start_index = batch_num * self.settings.truncate
    end_index = start_index + self.settings.truncate

    batch_x = self.x_train_batches[:, start_index:end_index]
    batch_y = self.y_train_batches[:, start_index:end_index]
    total_loss, train_step, current_state, predictions_series = sess.run(
        [self.total_loss_fun, self.train_step_fun, self.current_state, self.predictions_series],
        feed_dict={
            self.batch_x_placeholder:batch_x, 
            self.batch_y_placeholder:batch_y, 
            self.hidden_state:current_state
        })
    return total_loss, current_state, predictions_series
# End of __train_minibatch__()

def __train_epoch__(self, epoch_num, sess, current_state, loss_list):
    """
    Trains one full epoch.

    :type epoch_num: int
    :param epoch_num: the number of the current epoch.

    :type sess: tensorflow Session
    :param sess: the session during training occurs.

    :type current_state: numpy matrix
    :param current_state: the current hidden state.

    :type loss_list: list of floats
    :param loss_list: holds the losses incurred during training.

    :type return: (float, numpy matrix)
    :param return: (the latest incurred lost, the latest hidden state)
    """
    self.logger.info("Starting epoch: %d" % (epoch_num))

    for batch_num in range(self.num_batches):
        # Debug log outside of function to reduce number of arguments.
        self.logger.debug("Training minibatch : ", batch_num, " | ", "epoch : ", epoch_num + 1)
        total_loss, current_state, predictions_series = self.__train_minibatch__(batch_num, sess, current_state)
        loss_list.append(total_loss)
    # End of batch training

    self.logger.info("Finished epoch: %d | loss: %f" % (epoch_num, total_loss))
    return total_loss, current_state, predictions_series
# End of __train_epoch__()

def train(self):
    """
    Trains the given model on the given dataset, and saves the losses incurred
    at the end of each epoch to a plot image.
    """
    self.logger.info("Started training the model.")
    self.__unstack_variables__()
    self.__create_functions__()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        loss_list = []

        current_state = np.zeros((self.settings.batch_size, self.settings.hidden_size), dtype=float)
        for epoch_idx in range(1, self.settings.epochs + 1):
            total_loss, current_state, predictions_series = self.__train_epoch__(epoch_idx, sess, current_state, loss_list)
            print("Shape: ", current_state.shape, " | Current output: ", current_state)
            # End of epoch training

    self.logger.info("Finished training the model. Final loss: %f" % total_loss)
    self.__plot__(loss_list)
    self.generate_output()
# End of train()
```

**Update**

After completing the [second part of the tutorial](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/tensorflow-rnn-api-2bb31821b185) and using the built-in RNN api, the problem is gone, which means there's either something wrong with the way I use my `current_state` variable, or changes to the tensorflow API caused something wacky to happen (I'm pretty sure it's the former, though). Going to leave the question open in case someone has a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that "it appears to work" is true and your test error is really getting lower.

An hypothesis I have is that the very last batch is corrupted with zeros at the end because the length of the data `total_series_length / batch_size` is not a multiple of `truncated_backprop_length`.   (I did not check that it does happen it is filled with zeros.  The code in the tutorial is too old to run on my tf version and we don't have your code.)  This final mini-batch with only zeros at the end could lead the final `current_state` to converge to all ones.  On any other mini-batch `current_state` would not be all ones.

You could try printing the `current_state` each time you run `sess.run`, in `__train_minibatch__`.  Or maybe just print it every 1000 mini-batches.

Comment: The test error does get lower - from ~6.7 to ~3.4. I tried your suggestion of looking at `current_state` at the minibatch level, and I get all 1s in every minibatch. My code is on [a github repo](https://github.com/ffrankies/tf-terry), if it helps (I'm trying to get the tutorial to run on a text-based dataset, so I've had to tweak the tutorial code quite a bit). Also, I do have 'pad' data at the ends of my matrix rows, but the problem persists even when I turn the data into one long array and re-shape that into minibatches.